# How does [controller] work in route attribute of Web API controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

consider this code snippet:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HotelsController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

I understand that putting `[controller]` in the route will make the URL just `api/hotels`. My question is how does it do this? Does it take the whole string and cut off the part that is in the square brackets (in this case 'controller')?. Thus, I can call the class `HotelsClass` and put `[class`] in the route and it accomplishes the same. Or, does it always have to be `[controller]` and it just recognizes that specific pattern?

I tried it the first way, expected it to work the same, but got an error in my application at the point where it maps the controllers, so I thought I would ask for clarity.

**EDIT:** I understand that the class should end in `Controller` and am not disputing that convention. I was just confused by the underlying mechanics of the `[controller]` token and how it worked, and didn't want to just blindly use something without knowing why it did what it did.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this link! I was in the docs couldn't find anything about it. I guess it's a case of you don't know what you don't know!

Comment: Tell me about it. That's the number one problem I have with some documentations!

Answer (score 1):

MVC and WebAPI (which is basically MVC without the V) rely on a number of conventions. One convention is that controllers ALWAYS have a name that ends with "Controller". There's no good reason to even want to break that convention, never mind to actually do it.

Comment: I understand. I was just wondering under the hood if this was just convention based and only worked like this, or if it just looked at that pattern and would work the same regardless of the name of the controller.

Comment: Having `Controller` as suffix to the controller class is a norm so that it becomes obvious that the class is a controller class. But at run time, the fact that this class inherits from `ControllerBase` is also plays a role for the framework during route mapping and deciding which controller to use for request processing.